# Looping through ipynb files in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

So if I have the same piece of code inside of 10 separate .ipynb files with different names and lets say that the code is as follows.

```
x = 1+1
```

so pretty simple stuff, but I want to change the variable x to y. Is their anyway using python to loop through each .ipynb file and do some sort of find and replace anywhere it sees x to change it or replace it with y? Or will I have to open each file up in Jupiter notebook and make the change manually?

Comment: Sure, this is possible. I'd suggest starting by opening an .ipynb in a text editor -- you'll see that .ipynb files are structured as JSON. You can then do a bit of research regarding how to read and write files in python, and how to work with JSON data.

Comment: Alright I will definitely do that, I just didnt know if this was possible or not I didnt want to completely pursue it if it wasnt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never tried this before, but the .ipynb files are simply JSONs. These pretty much function like nested dictionaries. Each cell is contained within the key 'cells', and then the 'cell_type' tells you if the cell is code. You then access the contents of the code cell (the code part) with the 'source' key.

In a notebook I am writing I can look for a particular piece of code like this:

```
import json
with open('UW_Demographics.ipynb') as f:
    ff = json.load(f)

for cell in ff['cells']:
    if cell['cell_type'] == 'code':
        for elem in cell['source']:
            if "pd.read_csv('UWdemographics.csv')" in elem:
                print("OK")
```

You can iterate over your ipynb files, identify the code you want to change using the above, change it and save using `json.dump` in the normal way.

Comment: This is great, thanks provides exactly what I need!, I checked it but unfrotunately I am too low to vote it u p sorry!